# jQuery animate() color of CSS triangle change - why isn't this working?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, sass

This syntax works with every other border I change with jQuery's `animate()` function:

```
$(".contact .inner:before").animate({borderTopColor: '#59b4de', borderLeftColor: '#59b4de', borderRightColor: '#59b4de', borderBottomColor: '#59b4de'}, 300);
```

But for my CSS triangle (that is acting as an indicator at the bottom of a popover I have) the change doesn't occur at all.

Here's the CSS/SASS for my triangle:

```
    .inner {
        margin: auto;
        padding-top: 20px;
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;

        &:before {
            border: solid;
            border-color: #3c6ea5 transparent;
            border-width: 14px 16px 0 16px;
            bottom: -107px;
            content: "";
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            right: -50px;
        }
    }
```

Why is the change not occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as how you can't select pseudo elements, you could use a little script to create a "[pseudo-pseudo-element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-)", or in other words you can insert a real element with [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and animate that instead.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4XeZp/3/)**

```
<div class="inner">hello world</div>

$(".inner").prepend('<div class="tri"/>');
$('.tri').animate({
    borderTopColor: '#59b4de',
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: '#59b4de'
}, 300);

.inner {
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
.tri {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #3c6ea5 transparent;
    border-width: 14px 16px 0 16px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -107px;
    right: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer - jQuery can't animate CSS properties of pseudo elements.